# How to get bluetooth pair-able & discover-able status

Tags: linux, python-3.x, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there any way to get to know bluetooth pair-able & discover-able status such as pair-able On or Off in raspberrypi-3 using python 3.6 or linux command ?

I am using bluetoothctl functionality , through that i can change the pair-able & discover-able state from On to Off vise versa ,but unable to get current state.

if any way to get it , kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a language tag or show your code.

Answer (score 0):

btmgmt can do the work.

```
# btmgmt info
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
        addr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX version X manufacturer XX class 0x000000
        supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr hs le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy static-addr 
        current settings: powered connectable discoverable bondable ssp br/edr le advertising secure-conn 
        name XXXXXXXX
        short name XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this library: https://pypi.org/project/btmgmt/ .
According to the page, it was tested with Python 3.7 .